# Missing XMLReader in my PHP version?

Tags: php, wurfl

I'm trying to use the WURFL API for PHP. I'm getting the following error during its initialization.

```
Fatal error: Class 'XMLReader' not found in /var/www/html/wurfl-api/WURFL/Xml/AbstractIterator.php on line 89
```

my version of PHP when I run `php -v`:

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2010 16:21:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Why do you think I am getting this error? Is my version of PHP outdated?

Thank you!

Comment: check phpinfo() if it is activated or not in the ini file

Comment: aah i see, did not know that you need to enable an extension before you can use it (first time user, :)), thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have no XML extention installed. In RedHat like systems type `yum install php53-xml` in terminal. Or  you can simply add `phpinfo();` to your PHP code to rewiew your server configuration and find wether XML installed or not.

Comment: so i'm using Fedora 12, how can I enable this? I saw in the results of phpinfo() --disable-xmlreader, it seems that it is not installed.

Comment: yes, it could be `php53-xml` or `php-xml` on different distros.

Answer (score 9):

To install in debian based systems.

```
sudo apt install php7.2-xml
```

of course replace the php version with the version you are using.

You can check current used php version with :

```
php -v
```

After it is installed you will need to restart apache service if you are using it, or nginx.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

run `php -m` to check if the module is present

Comment: only a module called 'xml' is present, so i guess it's not. what can i do? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error while running the artisan command which reads files from excel on the development server via PuTTY.

And the solution is to change the excel extension from **xlsx** to **xls**.